# HTTP response for an unacceptable Accept header

Tags: api, http, rest

My RESTFul API can only respond JSON-encoded data (i.e. all my headers have `Content-Type: application/json`). What should I return, if the request has an `Accept` header that does not allow JSON (for example, `Accept: text/html`)? Should I just return a `400 Bad Request` with an explanation in the body, or is there a more specific status code for this exception?

Note that this is different from [unsupported request content-types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11973813/252239).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to be semantically correct:

If the request is HTTP/1.0:

a 406 Not Acceptable is the correct thing to return, as the client may not be able to handle a response that isn't of the type requested.

in HTTP/1.1, that's still the "right" thing to do, but there are exceptions,

From RFC 2616 Sec 10.4.7

```
 Note: HTTP/1.1 servers are allowed to return responses which are
      not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the
      request. In some cases, this may even be preferable to sending a
      406 response. User agents are encouraged to inspect the headers of
      an incoming response to determine if it is acceptable.
```

In truth, the likelihood of it mattering is pretty low, as @Jack has mentioned. I'm only including this answer in the interests of completeness.

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother.

There will be cases whereby consumers of your service wouldn't bother to set this header, e.g. when using `cURL` or `file_get_contents()` in PHP.

If your API documentation states that your service only supports JSON output, that should be good enough.

You could also work with extensions to enforce the format, e.g. `/path/to/resource.json?a=b` or `/path/to/resource.xml?a=b` for JSON and XML respectively.

In the case that you want to support multiple output formats and the `Accept` request header value is non-conclusive, you should define a *default* output format.

Comment: So you say just return the usual response with `Content-Type: application/json` anyway?

Comment: Ok, that's simple enough. What would you do, on the other hand, if the API would support both JSON and something else, say Bencode (`application/x-bencode`), but the request specified something third, say, `Accept: text/xml`? (I know this is not part of my original question.)

Comment: @AttilaO. I've updated my answer to be more canonical in regards to your question.

Comment: Very nice. I know some APIs like to use the extension to define a response format, but that's less flexible than the header (think `Accept: application/json, text/xml`). Defining a *default* output format makes the most sense imo, thanks.

Comment: @AttilaO. It may be less flexible, but in many cases: "explicit" > "implicit" :)