# For REST services that consume multiple formats, is there a generally accepted default Content Type?

Tags: rest, http, mime-types

If you have a REST service that accepts multiple formats:

- JSON
- XML
- HTML form data

Is there a widely accepted 'default' Content Type or:

- You pick it yourself based on the most frequent / common use case
- Don't accept a missing content type, require it explicitly by consumer

For example, according to W3C the default content type for POST via HTML, is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *strongly suggest* that a server should reject a request that has a missing or inappropriate `Content-Type` header.  [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13) Has an explicit code for such:

> #### 6.5.13.  415 Unsupported Media Type
>
> The 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status code indicates that the
> origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload
> is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated
> Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the
> data directly.

Even though it doesn't explicitly mention a *missing* Content-Type, this is the accepted practice. See: [HTTP status code for unaccepted Content-Type in request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973813/http-status-code-for-unaccepted-content-type-in-request)

Comment: Absolutly is at odds with the HTTP RFC: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1 as it indicates that content type is a 'should' (not 'must'), the receiver 'may' guess.   Still, I see your opinion is to  fall on the `No` side  of "may guess"

Comment: Hmm... looks like RFC 2616 has been superseded by several: RFC7xxx

Comment: The new RFC 7231 you refernce still has the 'should' and 'may' clauses, but includes a bunch of additional notes strongly indicating the contributers lean in the directions of 'Not guessing/sniffing'  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5

Comment: if you convert 'absolutely' to just 'strongly suggest' I'll mark you're answer correct as it pointed me in the direction of the newer RFC.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you should send the content-type in a response, you should also expect to have a content-type in the request.

Also, it's quite common to expect the correct content-type, see [Jira REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis) for instance:

> Make sure the content type in the request is set to 'application/json', as shown in the example.

Or [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types), where they have a list of accepted content-type and say:

> If the content-type header does not match the media, Twilio will reject the request.

And I'm pretty sure that also the [Outlook Mail REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) needs it to be correctly set.

So, yes, I'd say:"Don't accept a missing content type".